# Why does the *dirty* in *dirty mind* refer to sex instead of any type of immoral thought?

Tags: phrases, connotation

Why does the *dirty* in *dirty mind* refer to sexual-related thoughts instead of any type of immoral thought (including ill will or malice against another)?

Comment: This is a GP: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dirty-minded

Comment: No, all sex is dirty because it's enjoyment, and carnal, too. Utterly immoral. You should remain a virgin all your life and join a monastery. Or at the very least marry young and have sex with the same person always, with the exclusive purpose of making babies. As many as you possibly can. So teach us orthodox desert religions...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cultural attitudes towards sex, not English language as such.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I voted to close.

Comment: > If a "dirty mind" means to have sexual thoughts, then something must be said to refer to a person's bearing malice against another person. The mind you describe in this sentence immediately makes me think of the word [sadistic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sadism). A sadistic mind would be contemplating malicious fantasies.

Comment: @FumbleFingers How is it not about the English language?

Comment: While there is a question in the title, it is not really answerable in a meaningful way. Further, there doesn't seem to be any actual question in the body, despite the attachment of question marks to rhetorical statements.

Comment: @horatio Yeah. I agree. Hence, I voted to close.

Comment: @horatio I would have thought why *dirty* thoughts have to refer to specifically sexual immorality rather than immorality in general. But then... eh...

Comment: There are a couple of implied questions in the body: Why does “dirty” relate specifically to sex in this context, and what adjective would be appropriate to describe a mind that is immoral but not specifically sexual? Which are sort of interesting questions, but the question should be put on hold until it's edited to clearly ask one or the other.

Comment: This is an etymology question about an idiom, and it almost certainly has an answer (although the answer may not be known). It is not "off-topic" by any stretch of the imagination. I am nominating this question to be reopened.

Comment: @phenry Did you see the post before it was edited? It was sort of a rant and a single-word-request rolled into one, without a clear actual question. It's much better in its current form. (Also, note that the **OP** voted to close his own question.)

Comment: @BraddSzonye - Then the system works: the questioner improved the question and it should be reopened in its current form. (However, it never was "off-topic"; it was simply a low-quality question.)

Comment: @phenry I voted to re-open too. I disagree about topicality, however – an unanswerable “question” is off-topic for SE in general, not just ELU. I piggybacked on FF's close reason as being close enough, given the explanations in comments. The system worked, and the OP got useful feedback, so I wouldn't fret too much about the exact menu options chosen along the way. Perhaps “unclear what you're asking” would have been better, but it's moot now.

Answer (score 3):

*Dirty* has meant, in the OED’s definition, ‘morally unclean or impure; “smutty”’ for over 400 years. It is perhaps not too hard to see a progression of meaning from unclean to morally impure to sexually implicit or explicit.

Comment: I wish there is a term for morally unclean and impure without the sexual part, particularly if a person is a criminal, but not a *sexual criminal*.

Comment: @Anonymous There are words; e.g. adjectives such as: 'crooked, devious, dishonest, fraudulent,insidious, knavish, underhanded, unfair, unscrupulous, anti-social,corrupt, unethical, vicious, wicked, wrong, bad, depraved, dissolute, unprincipled', and nouns such as : thug, villian, thief, swindler etc. None of those imply any sexual immorality.

Comment: @WS2 Yeah. I suppose you're right. It's funny how "dirty mind" implies sexually immoral mind specifically, and you have to use different terms for non-sexual immorality. Maybe it's how English developed.

Comment: @Anonymous There is an expression of 'dirty money', and an offence of 'money laundering' which implies that the money was dirty in some way. These do not necessarily mean that the money was the product of the sex industry. I think the most frequent users of money launderers are drug cartels. Equally people talk of someone being mixed up in some 'dirty business'. That does not usually mean sex. So 'dirty' is widely used for criminality and immorality outside of sexual matters. There are other uses of 'dirty' too. A footballer who fouls others is said to be a 'dirty player'.

Comment: Meanwhile, someone who "plays dirty" cheats in the game.

Comment: This should not be confused with "foul play", which is *murder*.

Comment: Catholic upbringing here: Impure thoughts will lead to impure acts. Something that is impure is said to be unclean, i.e., dirty and therefore, an impure mind is equivalent to a dirty mind. In other words, if someone is *white* and *innocent* and *pure*, another person's lewd thoughts will distort and *soil* that image of innocence and chastity.